# Jenkins plugin code that should excute before any kind of job is run in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am new to Jenkins plugin development. 
 M trying to write a plugin that should be executed **before** any **Multi configuration type job** runs in Jenkins.
In this plugin I want to write rules that will **check what configuration parameters user has selected** while submitting the job, based on selected parameters, I want to decide whether to **allow the job to run or to restrict it**. 

User should be shown reason as to why that job cannot be run in the **Console Output.**

Does anyone have any ideas which class I need to extend or which interface I need to implement in order to get a hook into Jenkins job run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Blocked queue job plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Block+queued+job+plugin) was what I needed
Out of the box that plugin supports two ways to block the jobs -

1. Based on the result of last run of another project.
2. Based on result of last run of the current project

In that plugin the BlockQueueItemTaskDispatcher.java extends Jenkin's QueueTaskDispatcher providing us a hook into Jenkins logic to allow or block the jobs present in the queue from running. 
I used this plugin as a starting point for developing a new plugin that allows us to restrict project based on parameters selected and the current time. Ultimate goal is to restrict production migrations from running during the day.
Overriding the isBlocked() method of QueueTaskDispatcher gave access to hudson.model.Queue.Item instance as an argument to me. Then I used the Item instance's getParams method to get access to build parameters selected by the user at runtime. Parsed the lifecyle value from it. Checked the current time. If lifecycle was Production and current time was day time then restricted the job by returning non null CauseOfBlockage from isBlocked() method. If that condition was false, then returnedCauseOfBlockage as null allowing the queued job to run.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the [Matrix Execution Strategy](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Matrix+Groovy+Execution+Strategy+Plugin) which allows for a groovy script to select which matrix combinations to run. I would think if your script threw an exception it would stop the build.

For background, the multi configuration projects run a control job (or flyweight) which runs the SCM phase then starts all the actual combinations. This plugin runs after the flyweight SCM checkout.

If nothing else, this will give you a working plugin to start from

Disclaimer: I wrote this plugin

Comment: I think this plugin wont be helpful. Let me elaborate my problem. Its a parametrized build. Having choice paramters - lifecycle (valid values are QA , QC , PROD), client name (valid values are client1, client2) etc. I want to restrict production builds for selected clients between 8:00 am to 3:30 PM. Do we have any plugin that will allow me configure rules to say that a build for client 2 must be blocked between 8:00 AM to 3:30 PM. Only after 3:30 PM it must go into the queue and then execute.